# How do i enable curl support for php 5.3.3?

Tags: fedora, php5, curl

Hi I have installed curl and curl-devel, but i still can't get curl to work with php.
My php config line:

```
'./configure' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs' '--with-gd' '--with-mysql' '--with-zlib' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--prefix=/php-5.3.3' '--with-config-file-path=/php-5.3.3' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config'
```

Installed curl packages:

```
curl.i386 7.16.4-1.fc7 installed 
curl-devel.i386 7.16.4-1.fc7 installed
```

After installing curl #yum curl it should auto enable it for php, but curl still not available in php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your php.ini file is extension=php_curl.dll commented out?

Comment: yes, its commented out.

Comment: Are you really running Fedora 7? Please, please upgrade. Fedora 7 reached end-of-life on 2008-06-13 and you are living on a security time-bomb waiting to explode. (That's not Fedora-specific, but true for any unsupported OS.) If you need a longer lifecycle, please consider CentOS or Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: can i reconfigure my php config line with --with--curl ? or need to compile php again ?

Comment: Yes :) thanks for your advice, i will work on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add --with-curl to php's configure

Or try this since you already compiled if you still have the source.. not sure

```
cd php-5.3.3/ext/curl
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Then enable the extension in php.ini. It will be a .so file not a .dll

Comment: Can i add --with-curl to the config manually ? or need to use phpize ?

Comment: I guess i got the source, i tried this: 
[root@wow bin]# phpize
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

Comment: Thanks to all, problem solved, i recompiled php and everything is fine now!